# JAVA using RandomAccessFile after seek is very slow. What is the reason?

Tags: java, performance, io, seek, randomaccessfile

This is my test code

```
long fileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 512L;
byte[] bts = new byte[8];

RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile("f:/test.data", "rw");
randomAccessFile.setLength(fileSize);

randomAccessFile.seek(0);
long time = System.nanoTime();
randomAccessFile.write(bts);
System.out.println("write1 use:" + (System.nanoTime() - time));

randomAccessFile.seek(1024 * 1024 * 256L);
time = System.nanoTime();
randomAccessFile.write(bts);
System.out.println("write2 use:" + (System.nanoTime() - time));
```

print

```
write1 use:181051
write2 use:2029338072
```

It can be seen that writing is 9 bytes twice and the second time is 10000 times slower than the first time.

So I would like to ask why the seek will cause the file to write so slowly. Is there any solution?

Comment: This has to create ~256MB of data when you do the seek the second time because of the huge offset. Why are you seeking so far ahead?

Comment: I'm developing a high speed http downloader,need to download multiple chunks at the same time,so I want seek file on chunk down response coming.

Comment: Test with smaller offsets to see if that delay is proportional. Alternatively, write out to chunked files first, then assemble after.

Comment: What's your OS and filesystem type?  For something like this to work and not be horribly slow, the OS and file system have to support [sparse files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file).  Otherwise, when you write to a large offset with no previous data in between, the system needs to create all the data as @tadman stated in his comment.  Note also that you can use [FileChannel.write(ByteBuffer src, long position)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#write(java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20long)) to write to an arbitrary location in a file without seeking.

Comment: Thx,my OS is windows 10 and filesystem type is NTFS,i try to use FileChannel.write(ByteBuffer src, long position),then still the same.But i use FileChannel.map(),this is very fast.However, there is a problem that the maped file cannot exceed 2GB.

Comment: NTFS requires explicitly setting a flag to create a sparse file.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365566(v=vs.85).aspx  See this question and the first answer for more details:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634362/what-is-the-use-of-standardopenoption-sparse

Comment: Thank you very much.I try to use Files.newByteChannel() with StandardOpenOption.SPARSE option.It is very fast

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to create a sparse file. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file

```
final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(2);
buf.rewind();

final OpenOption[] options = {
    StandardOpenOption.WRITE,
    StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW,
    StandardOpenOption.SPARSE
};
final Path path = Paths.get("/tmp/foo");
Files.deleteIfExists(path);

try (
    final SeekableByteChannel channel
        = Files.newByteChannel(path, options);
) {
    channel.position(1L << 31);
    channel.write(buf);
}
```

The code was taken from [What is the use of StandardOpenOption.SPARSE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634362/what-is-the-use-of-standardopenoption-sparse)